# Type Constraint on foreach using LINQ extensions

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have seen a method somewhere here on SO to restrict items returned from a foreach loop to a certain type, using, if I remember correctly, LINQ extensions on IEnumerable and a lambda for the type check.  I can't find it again, can anyone suggest how this was achieved?

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean with "items returned from a foreach loop".

Comment: @Thomas, a foreach loop actually creates an enumerator, not individual items, and the enumerator yields ('returns') objects, but I was just aiming for brevity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this with a call to the Where extension method, as follows:

```
foreach(var x in theCollection.Where(i => i.GetType() == typeof(DesiredType))
{
     // Do something to x
}
```

But this is so useful that it is built into the .NET framework, and that is what Chris is pointing out above. IEnumerable has an extension method called OfType, documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx).

To use it, you'd do something like this:

```
foreach(var x in theCollection.OfType<int>())
{
     // Do something to x
}
```

Comment: Note that it's not exactly the same - calling GetType() and then comparing with the equality operator will behave differently in inheritance situations. The "is" operator (i.e. Where(i => i is DesiredType)) is closer to OfType.

Comment: Yes, that's right. OfType asks the question "Can this be cast to that?", so it's more like the IsAssignableFrom() method on Type.

Answer (score 8):

Are you looking for this?

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> OfType<TResult>(
    this IEnumerable source
)
```